# Haskell: unnecessary reevaluations of constant expressions

Tags: performance, haskell, ghc

I am going to demonstrate the problem using the following example program

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

data Point = Point !Double !Double

fmod :: Double -> Double -> Double
fmod a b | a < 0     = b - fmod (abs a) b 
         | otherwise = if a < b then a 
                       else let q = a / b 
                            in b * (q - fromIntegral (floor q :: Int))

standardMap :: Double -> Point -> Point
standardMap k (Point q p) = 
   Point (fmod (q + p) (2 * pi)) (fmod (p + k * sin(q)) (2 * pi))

iterate' gen !p = p : (iterate' gen $ gen p)

main = putStrLn 
     . show 
     . (\(Point a b) -> a + b) 
     . head . drop 100000000 
     . iterate' (standardMap k) $ (Point 0.15 0.25)
    where k = (cos (pi/3)) - (sin (pi/3))
```

Here `standardMap k` is the parametrized function and `k=(cos (pi/3))-(sin (pi/3))` is a parameter. If i compile this program with `ghc -O3 -fllvm` the execution time on my machine is approximately `42s`, however, if I write `k` in the form `0.5 - (sin (pi/3))` the execution time equals `21s` and if I write `k = 0.5 - 0.5 * (sqrt 3)` it will take only `12s`.

The conclusion is that `k` is reevaluated on each call of `standardMap k`.

Why this is not optimized?

P.S. compiler ghc 7.6.3 on archlinux

**EDIT**

For those who are concerned with the weird properties of `standardMap` here is a simpler and more intuitive example, which exhibits the same problem

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

data Point = Point !Double !Double

rotate :: Double -> Point -> Point
rotate k (Point q p) = 
   Point ((cos k) * q - (sin k) * p) ((sin k) * q + (cos k) * p)

iterate' gen !p = p : (iterate' gen $ gen p)

main = putStrLn 
     . show 
     . (\(Point a b) -> a + b) 
     . head . drop 100000000 
     . iterate' (rotate k) $ (Point 0.15 0.25)
   where --k = (cos (pi/3)) - (sin (pi/3))
         k = 0.5 - 0.5 * (sqrt 3)
```

**EDIT**

Before I asked the question I have tried to make `k` strict, the same way Don suggested, but with `ghc -O3` I didn't see a difference. The solution with strictness works if the program is compiled with `ghc -O2`. I missed that because I didn't try all possible combinations of flags with the all possible versions of the program.

So what is the difference between `-O3` and `-O2` that affects such cases?

Should I prefer `-O2` in general?

**EDIT**

As observed by Mike Hartl and others, if `rotate k` is changed into `rotate $ k` or `standardMap k` into `standardMap $ k`, the performance is improved, though it is not the best possible (Don's solution). Why?

Comment: Do you get similar results with ghc -O2 -fllvm or ghc -O -fllvm?

Comment: @jamesj Yes, it is even worse. I would expect that such things would be optimized in functional languages even without optimization flags.

Comment: You should probably add what versions of GHC and LLVM you are using.

Comment: @Changaco It is ghc 7.6.3 on archlinux

Comment: I know nearly nothing about optimizing Haskell, but does it help to force evaluation of `k` by means of `seq` before executing the other expression? It's just a wild guess from my side, and I don't have access to a compiler to test it. GHC is supposed to only compute constants once for as long as they are in scope.

Comment: @Changaco And LLVM 3.3-1, but if I omit `-fllvm` flag practically nothing changes

Comment: @kqr No, it does not, I have tried for example `!k = ...` and `seq k putStrLn ...`

Comment: This _is_ fascinating. On my machine, if I change `(standardMap k)` to `(standardMap $ k)` it's suddenly fast, even though I think this really shouldn't change anything. Is it the same for you? Also, inserting a trace into `k` makes it even faster.

Comment: Another question: using your first construct, I get the result `~2pi`. Using your fastest construct, I get `~pi`. Why?

Comment: @Stefan I don't know, I get `2pi` in all cases.

Comment: I think, it could be platform dependent handling of floating point numbers. I don't get, what exactly your algorithm is doing, but maybe it is not stable enough

Comment: @Stefan Yes, the iteration map is very sensitive to initial conditions, this kind of maps are used to study chaos.

Comment: Like @Stefan - I get different results for slow vs fast runs. Could rounding errors be causing substantially more iterations or some such?

Comment: @RichardHuxton No, the problem is more general, the one in question is just the example program I have made for this purpose only.

Comment: @MikeHartl: Inserting `$` between `standardMap` and `k` gives a speed up for me too.  That is bizarre.  I looked at the core and when `$` is there, the calculation of `k` is outside the loop.  When `$` is absent, the calculation of `k` is inside the loop.  Very weird (and rather worrying for anyone writing numerical codes in Haskell).

Comment: @MikeHartl Yes, I can reproduce this.

Comment: The difference between -O2 and -O3 is that 2 is an optimization level GHC supports, and 3 isn't. I suspect it's silently falling back to -O when you pass it -O3.

Answer (score 16):

As always, check the core.

With ghc -O2, k is inlined into the loop body, which is floated out as a top level function:

```
Main.main7 :: Main.Point -> Main.Point
Main.main7 =
  \ (ds_dAa :: Main.Point) ->
    case ds_dAa of _ { Main.Point q_alG p_alH ->
    case q_alG of _ { GHC.Types.D# x_s1bt ->
    case p_alH of _ { GHC.Types.D# y_s1bw ->
    case Main.$wfmod (GHC.Prim.+## x_s1bt y_s1bw) 6.283185307179586
    of ww_s1bi { __DEFAULT ->
    case Main.$wfmod
           (GHC.Prim.+##
              y_s1bw
              (GHC.Prim.*##
                 (GHC.Prim.-##
                    (GHC.Prim.cosDouble# 1.0471975511965976)
                    (GHC.Prim.sinDouble# 1.0471975511965976))
                 (GHC.Prim.sinDouble# x_s1bt)))
           6.283185307179586
    of ww1_X1bZ { __DEFAULT ->
    Main.Point (GHC.Types.D# ww_s1bi) (GHC.Types.D# ww1_X1bZ)
```

Indicating that the sin and cos calls aren't evaluated at compile time.
The result is that a bit more math is going to occur:

```
$ time ./A
3.1430515093368085
real    0m15.590s
```

If you make it strict, it is at least not recalculated each time:

```
main = putStrLn
     . show
     . (\(Point a b) -> a + b)
     . head . drop 100000000
     . iterate' (standardMap k) $ (Point 0.15 0.25)

    where
      k :: Double
      !k = (cos (pi/3)) - (sin (pi/3))
```

Resulting in:

```
ipv_sEq =
                      GHC.Prim.-##
                        (GHC.Prim.cosDouble# 1.0471975511965976)
                        (GHC.Prim.sinDouble# 1.0471975511965976) } in
```

And a running time of:

```
$ time ./A
6.283185307179588
real    0m7.859s
```

Which I think is good enough for now. I'd also add unpack pragmas to the Point type.

If you want to reason about numeric performance under different code arrangements, you must inspect the Core.

---

Using your revised example. It suffers the same issue. `k` is inlined `rotate`. GHC thinks it is really cheap, when in this benchmark it is more expensive.

Naively, ghc-7.2.3 -O2

```
$ time ./A
0.1470480616244365

real    0m22.897s
```

And `k` is evaluated each time rotate is called.

Make `k` strict: one way to force it to be not shared.

```
$ time ./A
0.14704806100839019

real    0m2.360s
```

Using UNPACK pragmas on the Point constructor:

```
$ time ./A
0.14704806100839019

real    0m1.860s
```

Comment: Good explanation of the behaviour of the resulting program, but I think the question why `k` is not shared remains a valid one.

Comment: Why does the result change after ``k`` is made strict?

Comment: Don, I don't know why you'd say that the `k` is floated out as a top level function.  Your core indicates that it's actually inlined and the cos and sin of the constant are calculated every time around the loop.

Comment: @Benjamin: for me there's no difference between using `!k` and using `k = 0.5 - 0.5 * (sqrt 3)`, but I'm using 7.4.1.

Comment: Correct, inlined into the loop body, which is floated out.

Comment: @TomEllis Did you complie with `ghc -O2`?

Comment: @DonStewart Can you please comment on my last edit of the original question?

Comment: ghc -O2 is preferred. ghc -O3 enables some optimizations that can cause things to  be worse.

Comment: @BenjaminBatistic: yes with `ghc -O2` is barely see a difference between the two.  `!k` is marginally faster.

Comment: @DonStewart So if I insist on a lazy `k`, I can not expect from GHC to optimize away the redundancy? If so, what is the reason?

Comment: What @JoachimBreitner said is definitely correct. The fact that `k` is not shared although it occurs in a `where` clause, is an obvious bug!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is repeated evaluation.

First, I switched to "do" notation and used a "let" on the definition of "k" which I figured should help. No - still slow.

Then I added a trace call - just being evaluated once. Even checked that the fast variant was in fact producing a Double.

Then I printed out both variations. There is a small difference in the starting values.

Tweaking the value of the "slow" variant makes it the same speed. I've no idea what your algorithm is for - would it be very sensitive to starting values?

```
import Debug.Trace (trace)

...

main = do
    -- is -0.3660254037844386
    let k0 = (0.5 - 0.5 * (sqrt 3))::Double
    -- was -0.3660254037844385
    let k1 = (cos (pi/3)) - (trace "x" (sin (pi/3))) + 0.0000000000000001;
    putStrLn (show k0)
    putStrLn (show k1)
    putStrLn
     . show
     . (\(Point a b) -> a + b)
     . head . drop 100000000
     . iterate' (standardMap k1) $ (Point 0.15 0.25)
```

---

EDIT: this is the version with numeric literals. It's displaying runtimes of 23sec vs 7sec for me. I compiled two separate versions of the code to make sure I wasn't doing something stupid like not recompiling.

```
main = do
    -- -0.3660254037844386
    -- -0.3660254037844385
    let k2 = -0.3660254037844385
    putStrLn
     . show
     . (\(Point a b) -> a + b)
     . head . drop 100000000
     . iterate' (standardMap k2) $ (Point 0.15 0.25)
```

EDIT2: I don't know how to get the opcodes from ghc, but comparing the hexdumps for the two .o files shows they differ by a single byte - presumably the literal. So it can't be the runtime.

---

EDIT3: Tried turning profiling on, and that's just puzzled me even more. unless I'm missing something the only difference is a small discrepancy in the number of calls to `fmod` (fmod.q to be precise).

The "5" profile is for the constant ending "5", same with "6".

```
        Fri Sep  6 12:37 2013 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

           constant-timings-5 +RTS -p -RTS

        total time  =       38.34 secs   (38343 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
        total alloc = 12,000,105,184 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE  %time %alloc

standardMap Main     71.0    0.0
iterate'    Main     21.2   93.3
fmod        Main      6.3    6.7


                                                          individual     inherited
COST CENTRE     MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN            MAIN                     50           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0                                  
 main           Main                    101           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                  
 CAF:main1      Main                     98           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                  
  main          Main                    100           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                  
 CAF:main2      Main                     97           0    0.0    0.0     1.0    0.0                                  
  main          Main                    102           0    1.0    0.0     1.0    0.0                                  
   main.\       Main                    110           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                  
 CAF:main3      Main                     96           0    0.0    0.0    99.0  100.0                                  
  main          Main                    103           0    0.0    0.0    99.0  100.0                                  
   iterate'     Main                    104   100000001   21.2   93.3    99.0  100.0                                  
    standardMap Main                    105   100000000   71.0    0.0    77.9    6.7                                  
     fmod       Main                    106   200000001    6.3    6.7     6.9    6.7                                                                                                
      fmod.q    Main                    109    49999750    0.6    0.0     0.6    0.0                                                                                                
 CAF:main_k     Main                     95           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                                                                                
  main          Main                    107           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                                                                                
   main.k2      Main                    108           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                                                                                
 CAF            GHC.IO.Handle.FD         93           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                                                                                
 CAF            GHC.Conc.Signal          90           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                                                                                
 CAF            GHC.Float                89           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                                                                                
 CAF            GHC.IO.Encoding          82           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0                                                                                                
 CAF            GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv    66           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0 


        Fri Sep  6 12:38 2013 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

           constant-timings-6 +RTS -p -RTS

        total time  =       22.17 secs   (22167 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
        total alloc = 11,999,947,752 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE  %time %alloc

standardMap Main     48.4    0.0
iterate'    Main     38.2   93.3
fmod        Main     10.9    6.7
main        Main      1.4    0.0
fmod.q      Main      1.0    0.0


                                                          individual     inherited
COST CENTRE     MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN            MAIN                     50           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main           Main                    101           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main1      Main                     98           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main          Main                    100           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main2      Main                     97           0    0.0    0.0     1.4    0.0
  main          Main                    102           0    1.4    0.0     1.4    0.0
   main.\       Main                    110           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main3      Main                     96           0    0.0    0.0    98.6  100.0
  main          Main                    103           0    0.0    0.0    98.6  100.0
   iterate'     Main                    104   100000001   38.2   93.3    98.6  100.0
    standardMap Main                    105   100000000   48.4    0.0    60.4    6.7
     fmod       Main                    106   200000001   10.9    6.7    12.0    6.7
      fmod.q    Main                    109    49989901    1.0    0.0     1.0    0.0
 CAF:main_k     Main                     95           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main          Main                    107           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   main.k2      Main                    108           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF            GHC.IO.Handle.FD         93           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF            GHC.Conc.Signal          90           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF            GHC.Float                89           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF            GHC.IO.Encoding          82           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF            GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv    66           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

---

EDIT4: Link below is to the two opcode dumps (thanks to @Tom Ellis). Although I can't read them, they seem to have the same "shape". Presumably the long random-char strings are internal identifiers. I've just recompiled both with `-O2 -fforce-recomp` and the time differences are real.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6462797

Comment: Isn't this a bug then? I found this problem in a completely different program, and the one in the question is just an example.

Comment: Are you sure tweaking k speeds it up?  I can't replicate that.

Comment: Does it for me with -O2 and literal k=...5 vs ...6. I get 23s v 7s. I've got ghc 7.4.1 if that matters (presumably not).

Comment: Try `ghc -fforce-recomp -O2 -ddump-simpl source-file.hs` if you want to see the core.

Comment: Note that what you linked to isn't really a disassembly ("opcode dump") but is GHC's Core representation. If you really want a disassembly `objdump -d` is always an option (although working from GHC's mangled names back to source names isn't always easy).